# how to apply mousemotion listener on a single cube using JOGL

Tags: netbeans, jogl

I had created a 3D cube in jogl using netbeans and want perform mouse drag event only on that single object by using mousemotion listener interface but the mouse drag event is also occured when i am adding other object in the canvas and the rotation of the cube and other object performs simultaneously but i just want to rotate the cube using mouse drag event so, please suggest me any solution for this problem thank you

**Box2.java**

```
    package Box2;
    import com.sun.opengl.util.Animator;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Frame;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import javax.media.opengl.GL;
    import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
    import javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas;
    import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
    import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;

    public class Box2 implements GLEventListener, 
                                 MouseListener, 
                                 MouseMotionListener
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Frame frame = new Frame("3D Box");
            GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas();
            canvas.addGLEventListener(new Box2());
            frame.add(canvas);
            frame.setSize(900, 780);
            final Animator animator = new Animator(canvas);
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
                {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            animator.stop();
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });
            // Center frame
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            animator.start();
        }
        // rotating the scene
        private float view_rotx = 80.0f;
        private float view_roty = 80.0f;
        // remember last mouse position
        private int oldMouseX;
        private int oldMouseY;

        public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
        {
            GL gl = drawable.getGL();

            // Set backgroundcolor and shading mode
            gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 1.0f, 0.3f, 0.0f);
            gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_FLAT);

            // give me some light
            float ambient[] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f };
            float diffuse[] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f };
            float specular[]= {0.2f,1.0f,0.2f,1.0f};
            float position[] = {20.0f,30.0f,20.0f,0.0f };
            gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_AMBIENT,ambient,0);
            gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse,0);
            gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_POSITION, position,0);
            gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT,GL.GL_SPECULAR, specular, 0);

            // and some red material
            float[] mambient ={0.1745f, 0.01175f, 0.01175f, 0.55f };
            float[] mdiffuse ={0.61424f, 0.04136f, 0.04136f, 0.55f };
            float[] mspecular ={0.727811f, 0.626959f, 0.626959f, 0.55f };
            float mshine =76.8f;
            gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT,GL.GL_AMBIENT,mambient,0);
            gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT,GL.GL_DIFFUSE,mdiffuse,0);
            gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT,GL.GL_SPECULAR,mspecular, 0);
            gl.glMaterialf (GL.GL_FRONT,GL.GL_SHININESS,mshine);
    //        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHTING);
    //        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT0);
    //        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    //        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_NORMALIZE);
            System.out.println("GL.GL_LIGHTING : "+GL.GL_LIGHTING);
            System.out.println("GL.GL_LIGHT0 : "+GL.GL_LIGHT0);
            System.out.println("GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST : "+GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

            drawable.addMouseListener(this);
            drawable.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }
        public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, 
                            int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {

            GL gl = drawable.getGL();
            GLU glu = new GLU();
            if (height <= 0) // no divide by zero
                height = 1;
            // keep ratio
            final float h = (float) width / (float) height;
            gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            glu.gluPerspective(45.0f, h, 1.0, 20.0);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
        }
        public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
        {
            GL gl = drawable.getGL();
            GLU glu = new GLU(); // needed for lookat

            gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            glu.gluLookAt(4,4,4,  // eye pos
                         0,0,0,   // look at
                         0,0,1);  // up

            gl.glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);       

            gl.glRotatef(view_rotx, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glRotatef(view_roty, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glTranslatef(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
            oneBox.drawMe(gl);
            oneBox.drawCircle(gl);
            gl.glFlush();
        }
        public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable drawable, 
                                  boolean modeChanged, boolean deviceChanged)
        { }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("mouseClicked called");}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("mouseEntered called");}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("mouseExited called");}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("mouseReleased called"); }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("mousePressed called");
            oldMouseX = e.getX();
            oldMouseY = e.getY();
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println("mouseDragged called");
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            Dimension size = e.getComponent().getSize();
            float thetaY = 360.0f * ( (float)(x-oldMouseX)/(float)size.width);
            float thetaX = 360.0f * ( (float)(oldMouseY-y)/(float)size.height);
            oldMouseX = x;
            oldMouseY = y;
            view_rotx += thetaX;
            view_roty += thetaY;
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    }



**oneBox.java**

package Box2;

import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;
import javax.media.opengl.GL;

/**
 *@author borres
 */
public class oneBox
{
    static void drawMe(GL gl)
    {
      /* draws the sides of a unit cube (0,0,0)-(1,1,1) */
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);/* f1: front */
            gl.glColor3f(0.3f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
            gl.glNormal3f(-1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);/* f2: bottom */
            gl.glColor3f(0.9f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
            gl.glNormal3f(0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);/* f3:back */
            gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
            gl.glNormal3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);/* f4: top */
            gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.6f, 0.7f);
            gl.glNormal3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);/* f5: left */
            gl.glColor3f(0.8f, 0.0f, 0.2f);
            gl.glNormal3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);/* f6: right */
            gl.glColor3f(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.6f);
            gl.glNormal3f(0.0f,-1.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glPopMatrix();  
    }
    static void drawCircle(GL gl)
    {
       gl.glTranslatef(-0.5f, 0.5f, -3.5f);
        gl.glPushMatrix();
            final float DEGREE_TO_RAD = (float)3.14 / 180;
            gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_LOOP);
            gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     
            int M_IN_DEGREE = 460;
            int N_IN_DEGREE = 100;
            for( int nR =N_IN_DEGREE; nR < M_IN_DEGREE; nR++ )
            {
                float fX = (float) sin((float)nR * DEGREE_TO_RAD );
                float fY = (float) cos((float)nR * DEGREE_TO_RAD );
                gl.glVertex2f( fX-5, fY-5 );
            }
            gl.glEnd();
        gl.glPopMatrix();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you should post some code. Anyway in theory when you drag, you modify a matrix and only that cube should use that matrix.

Comment: You shouldn't use deprecated OpenGL, start from a modern [Hello Triangle](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle), modify it to load a cube and then try to rotate it.

Comment: "com.sun.opengl.util" no longer exists in JOGL 2. You need to use picking to determine whether you click on your cube, see picking.java: http://jogamp.org/jogl-demos/src/demos/misc/Picking.java

Comment: You have to use GLU.createGLU(GL) instead of "new GLU()", you will get some unsupported operation exceptions if you don't follow my advice.